# Are pimcore events asynchronous?

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I am using pimcore (5.8, symfony 3.4), and have a simple question regarding (symfony) events: are they asynchronous from out of the box (ie without using packages implementing queues or anything)?

There doesn't seem to be any queue-related tables or anything, and it doesn't mention any asynchronous flow in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/event_dispatcher.html

So I'm guessing the answer is no?

Reason for asking is that some code that was previously in pimcore templates are now in custom API controllers (which simply exit with 'exit() at the end of their methods to avoid all sorts of other problems) but the issue I'm having is that event handlers are now not getting triggered.